# Why does Android Studio not have the delete option for androidTest and Test folder?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-girafee

For folders like main, Android Studio offers a delete option:
[image]

However, the option is not available for androidTest and test folders.
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

I am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Comment: Same issue with me when using Android Studio Giraffe. This version really messed up some easy-to-do actions present in earlier versions.